# Pattern Matching is not { } foo of nullable type keep showing it as nullable type

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, nullable-reference-types

I'm a little bit confused about the "is" operator, using VS2022 and Resharper after writing this:

```
//signature for the record
Task<int?> getIntIdAsync()

//code inserted into some function
if(await getIntIdAsync() is not int id) 
   return false
```

As Resharper suggest, changing `is not int id` to `is not { } id` and hovering `id` will result as `int`, so no more nullable `int?`

in this case:

```
//signature for the record
Task<Location?> getLocationObjectAsync()

//code inserted into some function
if(await getLocationObjectAsync() is not Location loc) 
   return false
```

`loc` will be a non-nullable `Location`, but if i swap from `is not Location loc` to `is not { } loc`, hovering `loc` show's a nullable `Location?` object.
Can someone explain me why?

Isn't `is not { }` meaning `is not null`? So if a nullable `Location?` is not null shouldn't be a `Location` object?

[From here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/patterns.md)

> The type pattern can be used to test values of nullable types: a value of type Nullable (or a boxed T) matches a type pattern T2 id if the value is non-null and the type of T2 is T, or some base type or interface of T. For example, in the code fragment
>
> ```
> int? x = 3;
> if (x is int v) { // code using v }
> ```
>
> The condition of the if statement is true at runtime and the variable v holds the value 3 of type int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `loc` is `Location`.

Let's consider this snippet:

```
#nullable enable
class Location {}

Location? l = new Location();

if(l is Location l2) Console.WriteLine(l2.GetType());
if(l is {} l3) Console.WriteLine(l3.GetType());


int? i = 3;
if(i is int i2) Console.WriteLine(i2.GetType());
if(i is {} i3) Console.WriteLine(i3.GetType());
```

This produces:

```
Submission#15+Location
Submission#15+Location
System.Int32
System.Int32
```

---

I suspect that Resharper sugget `is (not) {}` pattern because it's more general.

Let's consider:

```
#nullable enable
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
void F(object arg1, [CallerArgumentExpression("arg1")] string arg1Exp = "?") => Console.WriteLine($"'{arg1Exp}' => {arg1}");

void CheckIfNull<T>(T o)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value being checked is '{(o?.ToString() ?? "null")}'. Type: {typeof(T)}");
    F(o is int);    // This works only for int?/int
    F(o is {});     // This works for all types
}


int? i = 3;
CheckIfNull(i);

string s = "Hello";
CheckIfNull(s);
```

This prints:

```
Value being checked is '3'. Type: System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]
'o is int' => True
'o is {}' => True
Value being checked is 'Hello'. Type: System.String
'o is int' => False                 <----- Oops. We just meant to check for null/not_null
'o is {}' => True
```

We can see that o is int for a string gives `False` which may not be what you want if you're just checking for null / not_null.